# Checkbox in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 checkbox of Food  names like  Noodles,Pizza,Coke.If any of two are selected ,how to display in label box

```
  Food:<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Noodles" />
       <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Pizza" />
       <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Text="Coke" />
       <br />
       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
       <br />
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onClick="Button1_Click" />
```

So when if iam checking Noodles and pizza ,label 1 should display both the item.

Comment: Please post your code showing your effort so far. What error messages are you getting when running your code? What have you tried and where did you get stuck? As the question looks now, you're just asking us to write code for you, which is not what SO is about.

Comment: Yes i have tried like this string  checkeditem = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", CheckBox1.Checked, CheckBox2.Checked,CheckBox3.Checked); which gives me true or false but not the text .

Comment: I think it would be better to use a CheckBoxList. The way you have, you have to first check each one if they are checked :)    if (checkbox1.checked) label1.text=checkbox1.text;

Comment: CheckBox List iam able to get results but my requirement is using seperate checkboxes and get results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes as below in aspx file

```
Food:<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Noodles" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Pizza"  OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Text="Coke"  OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
   <br />
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
   <br />
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onClick="Button1_Click" />
```

In you code behind(aspx.cs) file,

```
protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         List<CheckBox> foodCheckBoxList = new List<CheckBox>();
         foodCheckBoxList.Add(CheckBox1);
         foodCheckBoxList.Add(CheckBox2);
         foodCheckBoxList.Add(CheckBox3);
         foodCheckBoxList.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x=>x.Text);
         Label1.Text = string.Join(",", foodCheckBoxList.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Text));
    }
```

This code will add text in your label on each checkbox selection.

If you want on your button click then move the above code inside your button click event and remove autopostback attribute and CheckBox_CheckedChanged event from each check box of aspx web page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wouldn't having a list of your checkboxes, and looping through that checking for checked and building your string be cleaner? Ifs work if you only have some 3-4 or so maybe, but when you get up a bit in number you'd have a lot less copied up code that way. Even neater of course would be automatically going through the checkboxes, but I'm not too sharp on ASP, so not sure exactly how that'd work, or if there's any obvious pitfalls to it...

Comment: List<CheckBox> foodCheckBoxList = new List<CheckBox>();
  foodCheckBoxList.Add(CheckBox1);
  foodCheckBoxList.Add(CheckBox2);
  foodCheckBoxList.Add(CheckBox3);
  foodCheckBoxList.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x=>x.Text);
  Label1.Text = string.Join(",", foodCheckBoxList.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Text)); Did you mean like this?

Comment: Thanks  for the answer

Comment: You can use a collection initialiser for the list, but pretty much like that, yeah @AnoopH.N

Answer (score 1):

`CheckBoxList` collection control is ideal for your situation, but since you said you can't do that, you can easily achieve this by looping through your controls like this:-

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<string> selectedFood = new List<string>();
   foreach (Control ctrl in form1.Controls)
   {
       if (ctrl is CheckBox)
       {
           CheckBox chkBox = ctrl as CheckBox;
           if (chkBox.Checked)
           {
                selectedFood.Add(chkBox.Text);
           }
       }
   }
   Label1.Text = String.Join(",", selectedFood);
}
```

Or it can simply done by using Linq:-

```
var selectedFood = form1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                        .Where(x => x.Checked)
                        .Select(x => x.Text); 

Label1.Text = String.Join(",", selectedFood);
```

Comment: This works perfect if there are only three checkboxes in the whole web page belonging to the category "Food". If there are checkboxes for some other category, then the label will be assigned with all the checkbox texts which exist in the web page. By the way, I liked the way of your coding.

Comment: @AnoopH.N - Yeah but OP never asked for that requirement, to answer your question those checkbox can reside inside a _Container_ on which we can loop through instead of the whole form.